# Elegant Ribbon error on setup

Tags: c#, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

I am trying to setup Elegant ribbon on my pc, the execution file downloaded from:
http://elegant-ribbon.software.informer.com/download/
then when I am trying to install it on my pc,I get the following error:

> ElagantRiboon\Samples\CS\CommandsSample\CommandEventsDataset.xss An error occured while trying to read the source fiile:
>   the source file is corrupted.

[image]

I am using windows 8.1, I tried on windows7 also I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Some Reason, Error Occurred because I have damaged bits on execution file.